# Return a reference of map item from a function

Tags: solidity, mapping

Hello Solidity Community,

I have a chunk of code that repeats a lot, wondering if I could make a function or something to shorten it. Similar chunks of code appear a lot as well.

```
Skin memory skin = skins[skinId];
require(skin.author != address(0), "Skin not registered yet.");
```

Does something like this make sense:

```
function _getSkin (uint256 skinId) private view returns (Skin memory) {
  Skin memory skin = skins[skinId];
  require(skin.author != address(0), "Skin not registered yet.");
  return skin;
}
function doStuff (uint256 skinId) public {
  Skin memory skin = _getSkin(skinId);
  skin...........
}
```

And if it doesn't, let me know why, and is there a standard pattern for solving this type of inconvenience, since it occurs a lot in my code, or is this something I shouldn't worry about?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a good idea to create a `_getSkin` function instead of repeating the same code always remember DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself).

- This will make your code easier to understand and maintain.
- This will also reduce the size of your contract, which can save on the cost of deploying your contract.

Your contract bytecode will be smaller.

Comment: Thanks for elaboration!